# Disallow user to make a call when there are no more credits: Sinch Javascript SDK

Tags: sinch

My application allows unlimited instant messages for free, but takes credits for calls. I want to be able to disallow user to make a call when he does not have any more credits. How in a ideal scenario is this managed using javascript SDK?

I am coming from a standpoint, that although I am able to control this behavior through some validations in code itself, but what happens when the user is a hacker? He can go to console and call javascript methods of its own such as `removeListeners` and then `callClient.callUser(userId)`. How do you protect sinchClient in such case? Thanks.

Note: I am open to provide more information if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinch exposes a REST based callback mechanism to control your call flow. You can set a callback URL in the Sinch Portal under Applications >> Voice and Video settings. Each call will then trigger a Incoming Call Event (documented here: https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#callbackapi) and you can control whether or not to connect this call via the callback response.